# Issue with My.Settings using Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, visual-basic, settings

For my A2 Computing project I have created a game using Visual Basic. For the leaderboard section, I have used the My.Settings feature to store the scores when the game closes, but only one or two actually save. My teacher doesn't know and I can't find anything helpful after a google search of the problem

Comment: Welcome to Programmers SE. This is a technical question, as opposed to the kind of questions we answer here, which are more concept oriented. Try asking in the Stack Overflow network (be sure to include the part of your code relevant to your question or a code example, as this question is not suitable for answering without it), and be sure to come back here if you have conceptual  programming questions. We'll be glad to help! Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force a save of the My.Settings object using `My.Settings.Save()`, however I'd suggest you look into writing a file to disk and using that to store your high scores. It's much better and it's a good opportunity to teach yourself about File I/O.

Here's a good tutorial on how to do that via MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: No problem, but as written above by @ArthurChamz, this is a more technical question (as opposed to a more abstract one about programming in general) that really belongs on Stack Overflow. In the future if you have another question along these lines, people will be happy to help over there. Good luck on your learning :)